# ASP.NET MVC make ajax calls after page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page with 6 charts. When user opens page for the first time, I want to load only the layout of the page, and then separately each chart with ajax, because it takes few seconds for each chart to generate on server side. Is it possible to do this with razor syntax using @Ajax.BeginForm, or is it better with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that it would be better to use jquery. The reason for that is that Ajax.BeginForm will output a form, and that would only make sense if you expect it to be used to send data back to the server.

If all you want to do is load the charts asynchronously it's probably best to use query, for example:

```
$(function(){
 $('#divForChart1').load('@Url.Action("ActionThatGeneratesChart1", "ChartController");
 $('#divForChart2').load('@Url.Action("ActionThatGeneratesChart2", "ChartController");
...
});
```

Comment: What JQuery event would I have to use to fire the ajax call to the server when page is loaded? $.ready is probably not appropriate since it fires each time page is loaded, regarding if it is loaded for the first time or is it loaded because of post back call.

Comment: There's no postback in the webforms sense in MVC (you are using MVC4 right?). So if you really have something in your page that posts back to itself, you will want to use the ready event since the whole page needs to be refreshed, including the charts.

Comment: Yes I am using MVC 4. If I understand correctly ready event fires only when page is loaded for the first time and does not fire when ajax call is finished?

Comment: @gappani yes that is correct, but you should be aware that fires when DOM is ready (so it fires before images, css laods up)